# HttpClient not returning json value of URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use HttpClient to GET information from Jira, but I am unable to see any of the information. I want to be able to get all the bugs that match certain filters so that I can add them to a table in my program.

I have tried to access Jira with the rest api, but every time I do it says that the issue or project doesn't exist. The thing is that if I enter the URI into the bar at the top of my browser I can see the JSON text that I want. This leads me to believe that the reason my code is not returning these values is because of an authorization issue. I am using basic auth to send my credentials. I also want to add that I used cURL in cmd to test my credentials with basic auth and it worked.

```
public async Task<JiraModel> GetBugs()
        {
           using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = "https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/VCMF";

                String username = "username";
                String password = "apikey";
                String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/VCMF");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JiraModel>(content);
            }
        }
```

I should be getting the json results in string form by the end of this length of code, but I keep getting a 404 error instead that for this code specifically says "No project could be found with key 'VCMF'".

Comment: Are you base64 encoding the colon when you use curl?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I can get the json script in cURL using the actual credentials or the base64 UTF8 encoded credentials. The instructions I am using are here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-basic-authentication/

Comment: Looks like they want the colon encoded... weird. There goes my idea :). One thing though; you might want to read [this article about how to use `HttpClient`](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're creating the authorization header incorrectly.

The constructor you're using for `AuthenticationHeaderValue` class takes two arguments: scheme and parameter:

```
public AuthenticationHeaderValue(string scheme, string parameter)
{
}
```

The first argument should be the scheme (Basic in this case) and the second, the base64-encoded credentials:

So instead of:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

It should be:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);
```

Hope this helps!